# JS Charts and html table overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

using JS charts:

http://www.jscharts.com/

This is the example, of what I am talking about, **chart is overlapping table**

http://char.web44.net/

I think it has something to do with layout, any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I don't have experience with jscharts, but there is a div inside div#graph that has margin-top set to -321px which is causing the overlap - did you see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a margin-top of -321px on a div (the jscharts logo) inside of div#graph and it's pulling the content after #graph. You need to set a height on the #graph div, then everything will be pushed down correctly.